# how can i get value from database into dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net, .net

dropdown list was  automatically generating number sequence. after selecting value from the database it showing same as the auto generated dropdown list

```
e ddlDuration.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        ddlDuration.DataBind();
        ddlDuration.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Customer--", "0"));
```

this code I used for generating numbers.

```
ddlDuration.SelectedIndex = ddlDuration.Items.IndexOf(ddlDuration.Items.FindByValue(oList[0].Duration));
```

and this for reading data from the list. the value can get till the

*oList[0].Duration*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Raheez,**

It may be happening because the value of oList[0].Duration is not in 1-100 range.

Or

Try this :

ddlDuration.SelectedIndex = ddlDuration.Items.IndexOf(ddlDuration.Items.FindByValue(oList[1].Duration.Trim()));